# How to indicate a custom radio button is selected

Tags: css, radio-button

I have custom radio buttons. I had to hid the display of the original radio buttons to create these large custtom buttons. I want to let the user click on a button and the button change color to indicate the user has selected it.

```css
<style>
          #main_page {
          background: #34357c;
          padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
          width: 900px;
          height: 600px;
          font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: -1;
          margin-top:315px; 
          margin-left: 415px;
          }
    
        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
            margin-top: 25px !important;
            opacity: 0 
         }
        
        .radio-toolbar label {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size:25px;
            border: 2px solid #444;
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #daeaff;
            color: #4c4de4;
           }
        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background-color: white; 
        }
 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
             
        
        </head>
        <body>

    <div id= "main_page">
    
    <div class = "radio-toolbar">
    
    
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID1" value = "Husband"><label>Husband</label>
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID2" value = "Wife"><label>wife</label>

    </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a selector like

`input[type="radio"]:checked + label`

**[type="radio"]** is a selector of HTML properties.

**:checked** is a pseudo-class that allows us to apply a special style to the checked state of an input.

**+** is a selector of adjacent siblings

In this way, when an input type radio is checked, the adjacent label (which comes immediately afterwards) must assume the given style. Therefore, using the **+** combinator it is important that you place the elements in the right order in the HTML code.

Comment: Hi! I tried adding the selector like you said, but that did not seem to work. I just added the selector to the Code Snippet above in my original question so you can see it not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to relate the label to the input using the For attribute. That way, when you click on the label, the input will be checked.

Comment: What kind of selector would you use when a user wants to unselect the label they have previously selected?